# How can I selectively indent the content of a row in a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, delegates, qtableview

I am relatively new to QT Creator.

I have a specific need that requires me to indent the text inside a cell of some specific rows in a QTableView, according to a certain parameter. I am using a custom model subclassed from the QAbstractTableModel.

Below is my minimal example:

I have a Class named Variable which is the object that needs to be displayed on the QTableView. We will use 2 columns : 1 for the Name of variable and 1 for its Value. We only want to indent the *Name* of certain variables.

Each Variable object has a parameter called *IndentParameter* which will be our criterion.There are only 3 values for IndentParameter : 0 , 1 and 2.

If the IndentParameter is 0, nothing needs to be done. IndentParameter= 1 means we indent 1 time and paint the cell, and IndentParameter= 2 means we indent twice and paint the cell with a different color.

```
class Variable
{
public:
    Variable();
    ~Variable();
    
    QString getName() const;
    void setName(const QString newName);

    int getIndentParamater() const;
    void setIndentParamater(const int newInt);

    int getValue() const;
    void setValue(const int newValue);
    
private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_IndentParamater;
    int m_value;

};
```

The desired output could look something like this:
[Desired indentation on Variable Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XefqF.png)

At the moment the color differenciation is realized inside the model: (incomplete but just for clarification)

```
VariableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
if (role == Qt::BackGroundRole)
{
     if (VariableList.at(index.row())->getIndentParameter) == 1)
         return QBrush(Qt::cyan)
     if (VariableList.at(index.row())->getIndentParamater) == 2)
         return QBrush(Qt::green)
}
```

I have already tried adding "    " (blank spaces) to the name of the variables but I need their name to be intact for some other features to work properly.

Since I am using the Model View Architecture, I figured there could be a clever way of doing this via subclassing a Delegate but I have to admit I have never done this before and don't know much about them.

Thank you very much in advance for taking the time to read.

Comment: The correct way actually is to indent with spaces when returning data with `Qt::DisplayRole`. If you need the original name without the added spaces, then use other role for it (e.g. you can add you custom `role` constant). Making a delegate just because of this little indentation thing is too much of overkill. IMHO, YAGNI. Believe me.

Comment: Okay. I thought it would be appropriate to have a delegate do the job of this indentation, as we could transfer the painting duties along with it. I have done what you described though. I am returning the name of the variable prepended with blank spaces repeated **IndentParameter** number of times. Syntax is a little bit messy but it works just fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
class MyDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
    public:
      using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;

      void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        int indent = index->data(IndentRole).toInt();
        option->text.prepend(QString(' ', indent));
      }
};
```

then set this delegate to your view.
Here you add space only in data to be painted and this won't affect your model's data.

Another option is to reimplement the `QStyleItemDelegate::paint`, where you can directly draw your text. But here the example above is much more simple.